# "object at" address printed instead of output

Tags: python, object

```
from itertools import combinations

print(combinations(range(4), 2))
```

When I run:
$ python testing.py

I get this instead of the combination outputs.

**<itertools.combinations object at 0x7fb981c08d10>**

How do I get the actual output?

Answer (score 0):

try (wrap `combinations` with `list`). Explanation: What you get is an iterator - wrapping it with list return the data struct you are looking for. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for more.

```
from itertools import combinations

print(list(combinations(range(4), 2)))
```

output

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```